# Even though strings in python are immutable how is that sorted function works on it?

Tags: python-3.x

I tried to sort a string manually and when exchanging the characters I got to know that strings are immutable in python , then how is that the sort() and sorted() function perfectly works on strings ?

Comment: Really depends on what you want to do ? Are you dealing with words in sentences or character in word ? Can you edit the question by precising what you want to do, illustrated by an input example and the expected output.

Comment: @AlexandreB. I was dealing with characters in a word and had to sort  specified characters in the word . Below answers have cleared the doubt and provided better understanding about the manipulation of the string.

Answer (score 3):

Strings don't have a `sort` method:

```
>>> letters_str = "aebcdf"
>>> letters_str.sort()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    letters_str.sort()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'sort'
```

But you can pass a string into [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted). It does not change the string you passed into it. Instead, it returns a new `list` (not a `str`!). We can create a string from that list by using the `join` method, and assigning it to `letters_str`:

```
>>> letters_str = "aebcdf"
>>> sorted(letters_str) # Returns a list
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
>>> print(letters_str) # See, the string hasn't changed
aebcdf
>>> letters_str = "".join(sorted(letters_str))
>>> print(letters_str) # Now it has been changed for good
abcdef
```

`sorted` works for any *iterable*, which means it also works for *lists* and *tuples*:

```
>>> letters_list = ["a", "e", "b", "c", "d", "f"] # list("aebcdf")
>>> sorted(letters_list)
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

Answer (score 1):

The term 'immutable' suggests that the string itself cannot be changed but you can always read the contents of that string, and that's what the function 'sorted' does, it returns a list of characters in the string sorted lexically.

When you do this, you will notice that string1 was not changed.

```
string2 = ''.join(sorted(string1))
print(string1, string2)
```